# iOS views navigation best practices

Tags: ios

I'm very new in iOS dev (but have more then 10 years overall experience with other platforms so it should help). Now I have to create relatively complex iOS application and do it very fast :).

I created application based on 'Tabbed Application' template using storyboard. Then I added login view that uses JSON to communicate with web application. I made this view initial (first that user sees) by moving appropriate arrow from default tab bar controller to my 'login view controller'.

On the login view I have text fields and login button. By clicking button application verifies user's name and password and then navigate him to default tab bar controller (created by Xcode). I do it with this code:

```
WPFirstViewController *fvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"TabBars"];
[fvc setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
[self presentViewController:fvc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Everything works fine, but I'm confused than I didn't use graphics lines between views on storyboard and I'm not sure that my approach is correct.

So, questions is how should I navigate user from the login view to tab bar controller? What is the best way in my case? And also, how for example should I navigate user from one of the tab view controller pages page (for example, by clicking button 'Settings') to corresponding view and then back? Maybe somebody could share a link to some good article.

Sorry for the long text. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Your approach is fine (and Storyboards are good for minimising loc and errors especially with auto-layout) although you could have chosen to use a segue rather than presenting the view controller manually.

Comment: Thank you, Robotic Cat! It becomes more and more clear for me while I'm reading everything I can find about this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modal view controllers are supposed to be used for cases where you need to get some critical information from the user (or present some to the user), without which you can't continue with the app. A log in controller would be a good choice for a modal view controller, but your main controller, your tab bar controller isn't. It would be better to present the login controller modally from the controller in the first tab of your tab bar controller. If you do this from viewDidAppear, and with no animation, it will be the first thing the user sees. When the user successfully logs in, just dismiss that controller, and you'll be ready to go in your first tab.

I'm not sure what you mean by your second question. The user navigates between the tabs by clicking on a tab -- you don't need to do anything in code for that.

Comment: Thank you for reply! But it is still not clear to me. Why I should not make login view controller separated and the first one in application? Because main tab bar controller without username from user has no data to display, it must go to web application via json first to get this data after user successfully logged in. And login view is 'used once' view. Isn't it clearer to separate it?

Comment: @DmitrySikorsky, I think it's ok to have it the first one, but, you shouldn't then present your tab bar controller as a modal. If you want your login controller to be first, then when you're done with it, switch the window's root view controller to the tab bar controller. But many modal controllers are "used once" views, so I think the way  said is a very common way to do login controllers.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you not to use storyBoards. Also, if you are planning to have a navigation controller on your app, then you will definitely use the feature of pushing view controllers on a `self.navigationViewController` of your view controller. It's easy to use, really easy!!

Comment: Thank you for reply! Could you please explain what is negative result of using storyboards? (I know only that this feature supported by only iOS 5+.)

Comment: Storyboards are not easily manageable especially if you are using some versioning system. They provide a great solution for something quick, but not for something good. And as you said they work only for iOS 5+. Currently I write code that works for iOS 4.x+

Answer (score 0):

Typically, login view controllers should be modally presented with:   `presentModalViewController:animated:`

In regards to your UITabBarController, each tab can be a UINavigationController, which will enable you to maintain a stack of UIViewControllers.

All the remains is determining whether the view controller you want to present is modal, or part of said stack.